# Money format not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this bunch of code which formats the price money amount. And it works perfectly on single page i.e in core php page or any .php page. But the moment I put it in the view page of codeigniter project, it does not give me the right formatted amount.

My code is

```
$amount = '5804';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', ceil($amount));
echo substr($amount, 0, strpos($amount, '.'));
```

But when I put it in the view page of my codeigniter project like the following:

```
<?php 
        $amount = $product->selling_price;

        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
        $amount = money_format('%!i', ceil($amount));
        $myval = substr($amount, 0, strpos($amount, '.'));
        echo $myval; 
 ?>
```

It does not give me the formatted number in the above code.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: What does it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not what you are looking for but this works for me in codeigniter

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_IN', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $fmt->formatCurrency($amt, "INR");
```

You will need to enable the php extension intl, it's for internationalization.Goto php.ini, find the below line and remove the semi-colon and then restart wamp or xampp.

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```